# HTML inputbox to Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vbscript

Im trying to get three variables from HTML input boxes to a JavaScript that prints ZPL barcodes.
Below is the code I have:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">
        <title>TAG</title>
    <body>
        <form>
            <form name="TAG" action="" method="GET">
                Model:  <input type="text" name="Model" value="" id="ModelSku"><br>
                Serial: <input type="text" name="Serial" id="LabelSku"><br>
                SJM:    <input type="text" name="SJM" id="SAPSku"><br>
                <input type="Submit" value="Submit">

            </form> 
    </body>
    <script language="VBScript">
        document.getElementById('ModelSku').value;
        $("ModelSku").val();
        Set FileSysObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set ObjWshNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        Set ObjZebra = FileSysObj.CreateTextFile("lpt3:", True)

        ZPLText = "^XA"
        ZPLText = ZPLText & "^LH15,0"
        ZPLText = ZPLText & "^FO1,20"
        ZPLText = ZPLText & "^AsN,25,25"
        ZPLText = ZPLText & "^FD"
        ZPLText = ZPLText & "SJM Model:"
        ZPLText = ZPLText & ModelSku
        ZPLText = ZPLText & "^FS"
        ZPLText = ZPLText & "^FO1,80"
        ZPLText = ZPLText & "^AsN,25,25"
        ZPLText = ZPLText & "^FD"
        ZPLText = ZPLText & "Serial Number"

        ZPLText = ZPLText & "^FS"
        ZPLText = ZPLText & "^FO03,120"
        ZPLText = ZPLText & "^B3N,N,90,Y,N"

        ZPLText = ZPLText & "^FD"
        ZPLText = ZPLText & LabelSku

        ZPLText = ZPLText & "^FS"
        ZPLText = ZPLText & "^FO1,260"
        ZPLText = ZPLText & "^AsN,25,25"
        ZPLText = ZPLText & "^FD"
        ZPLText = ZPLText & "SAP Number"

        ZPLText = ZPLText & "^FS"
        ZPLText = ZPLText & "^FO03,300"
        ZPLText = ZPLText & "^B3N,N,75,Y,N"

        ZPLText = ZPLText & "^FD"
        ZPLText = ZPLText & SAPSku

        ZPLText = ZPLText & "^FS"
        ZPLText = ZPLText & "^XZ"

        ObjZebra.Write(ZPLText)
        objZebra.Close
        Set objZebra = Nothing

    </script>
</head>


</html>
```

The ModelSKU, LabelSku and SAPSku are the variables I need to pass from the input boxes to the ZPL text to print the barcodes.

Can anyone point me in the right direction. I have little knowledge of JavaScript some pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks all.

Comment: Where's the JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry its a vbscript been trying to do this so many ways but all failing.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, i understand that you want to send the HTML form values from the browser to the  VBScript.

I hope the following link can help you achieve it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk29wbb7%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

Please let me know if that helps you.